# NSURL fail able initialiser initWithString: does not return nil on empty String in Swift

Tags: swift, nsurl

It is easy to reproduce in a Playground

```
import Foundation

let urlString = ""

let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

print(url)
```

The result of url is somehow `(no URL)` instead of the expected `nil`
and the printout is `Optional()` with neither `.Some` or `.None`.

I would really like some insight on this one, because it caught me by surprise and causes a crash in production code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After i filled a Radar for this i got the following answer:

> Apple Developer Relations
>
> An empty string is a valid URL string. It has no scheme, no authority (user/password/host/port), an empty path, no query and no fragment.

So it seems to be working as expected.

Comment: So what you mean is that the URL in swift 3 which is returning nil for an empty string is the one deserving a radar, right?

Comment: Wow, just tested it, `let url = URL(string: "")` and
`let nsurl = NSURL(string: "")` have different results

Comment: I know, my app crashed on me when i was doing the swift 3 migration and i couldn't figure out why it was working on swift 2 when after seing the documentation it really shouldn't, so i checked the empty strings now.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find out is to read the documentation

```
convenience init?(string URLString: String)
```

> **Return Value**
>
> An NSURL object initialized with URLString. If the URL string was malformed, returns nil.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This method expects URLString to contain only characters that are allowed in a properly formed URL. All other characters must be properly percent escaped. Any percent-escaped characters are interpreted using UTF-8 encoding.

So you have to check for `nil`

Comment: It does not return nil! Thats my problem